# Inclusion of Sobolev spaces with fractional order

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $W^{k,p}\mathbb(R^n)$ the usual Sobolev space.
We know that if $k>l$ and $1\leq p<q<\infty$, $(k-l)p<n$ and
$$\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{k-l}{n}$$
then
$$W^{k,p}\mathbb(R^n)\subseteq W^{l,q}\mathbb(R^n)$$
Is this true also if $k,l$ are non integers?

Comment: what is the motivation of this problem?